# Materials not showing in other programs

Tags: texturing, uv

I am new to blender and I am trying to import a model from the models resource (vibri from vib-ribbon), but the textures wouldn't show up in unity. So i opened blender and figured out how UV mapping worked. I got the texture that came with the model and got it mapped. Everything was mapped fine except the head. I was fine with it and exported it. But the model was still completely grey when I put it into unity. I thought i should try a different format cause maybe its way of storing materials aren't compatible with unity and tried another. All formats compatible with unity didn't work. The materials all default to grey.
Here is the texture i used:  [image: A texture of a white rectangle taking up the left side and a black rectangle taking the other.]       and how vibri looks with it:[image: Vibri 3D model with previous texture applied]

Would anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: Read through https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures and see if it applies here.